# How would i convert a GCP Service Account JSON string to Dataform Credentials string?

Tags: string, google-cloud-platform, dataform

I have a GCP Service Account JSON key, that needs to be converted to a Dataform Credentials Template, as mentioned below. Basically, newlines have to be converted to \n , and some more transformations. Would there be an easy way to do this?

```
{
  "projectId": "prj-dfad-4curtool-d-c818",
  "credentials": "{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "prj-xxxx-xxx-x-xxx",
    "private_key_id": "35cf...27b",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE...ZNwub\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "xxx@prj-x-xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "102742287670708666429",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxx@prj-x-xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }",
  "location": "US"
}
```

to the Dataform Credentials like this

```
{
  "projectId": "prj-dfad-4curtool-d-c818",
  "credentials": "{\r\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",\r\n  \"project_id\": \"prj-xxxx-xxx-x-xxx\",\r\n  \"private_key_id\": \"35cf...27b\",\r\n  \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIE...ZNwub\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",\r\n  \"client_email\": \"xxx@prj-x-xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\r\n  \"client_id\": \"102742287670708666429\",\r\n  \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\r\n  \"token_uri\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\r\n  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\r\n  \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxx@prj-x-xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"\r\n}\r\n\r\n",
  "location": "US"
}
```

Comment: It's not compliant? What's your error?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to replace control chars (e.g. newline) with escaped equivalents (e.g. `\n`).

> **NOTE** Because you've `\r` (carriage returns), I assume you're using a Mac or Windows machine. So, the command may be slightly different. I've kept the carriage-return (`\r`) and newline (`\n`) separate so that this will work on Linux where carriage-returns aren't used.

On Linux:

```bash
CREDENTIALS=$(more /path/to/key.json | sed \
--null-data \
--expression='s|\r|\\r|g' \
--expression='s|\n|\\n|g' \
--expression='s|"|\\"|g')

echo "{\"credentials\":\"${CREDENTIALS}\"}"
```